# Clear region with menu's per url cache

Tags: 8, blocks, navigation

I have a region with menus, a menus displays depending on the url example if on the about page(sitename/about-us), display about menu and links as a sub menu.

It works, but the problem is after navigating through the site a couple of times, the region caches. is the anyway i can clear the regions cache on page reload.

I tried the below in my .theme

```
   /**
   *  Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
   */
  function themename_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
    //the menu block id name in the region
    if ($vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == 'submenu') {
      //-- This stops the block being cache in drupal 8
      $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

    }
  }
```

also tried

```
  /**
   * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
   */
  function themename_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
    if ($vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == 'theme-block-branding') {
      //-- This stops the block being cache in drupal 8
      $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
    }
  }
```

not sure what steps I can follow to achieve the above

Comment: This sounds better suited for Menu Block module as it accounts for this.

Answer (score -1):

Add code below:

```
class MYCUSTOMBLOCK extends BlockBase {
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#markup' => '', // the content of your block
    );
  }
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
   return 0; // No caching gets applied here
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stef not sure why this comment was down voted, could you possibly explain

Comment: Hi @Lloyd_07: try to load in the menu's in the '#markup' section. Then, place this custom block in your region. The getCacheMaxAge() function should make sure this block is not cached.

Comment: I don't see how this answer addresses the problem. The issue is that the region is being cached, not the block. So the region will clear out regardless of whether the block is cached.